# katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer make crashing the Gmail app

Tags: android, phonegap-plugins, email-attachments, cordova-plugins

[image]I used this plugin in my Android phonegap application.
When I tried to add the attachment and sending the mail, each time it is crashing the Gmail app and showing " Unfortunately Gmail has stopped" . I checked that file has data also.
But didn't find the solution.
Can any one help me please..
Thanks in advance
my sample code is {window.plugin.email.open({
                to: ['mymail@gmail.com'],
                subject: 'Testing the Mail Functionality with Attachment',
                body: "Hi",
                isHtml: true,
                attachments: ["JB/ReadingData.txt"]
            });}

I updated the screenshot, which I ma getting the error message in the ADT. I ma not able to send an email with out attachment also.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15389351/unable-to-send-email-with-attachments-from-my-app-using-intents-gmail?rq=1 ----- here I found the solution. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i am not worng its because your attachment file it is crashing please check path of .txt file or either leave attachment field as blank and check. Reffer read me file with katzer email plugin implementation example. If possible will post code for the same.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, without the reply also it is crashing. Only for sometimes it is working with out the attachment (like 1 out of 10)

Comment: Problem is with attachment file loading when using gmail changing Java code in EmailComposer.java inside function getUriForPath(String path) from Uri.parse() to Uri.fromFile() get work done.
If application is android/ios specific den you can also try this plugin:
https://github.com/GalCohen/EmailComposer-phonegap-plugin
Please vote up if answer is correct. :)