# Email Intent subject is ignored in gmail, but works with other mail clients

Tags: android, android-intent

For below mentioned code subject is getting displayed in other email accounts but the same is coming blank in gmail.

```
Intent j = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
j.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:appsupport@prali.in"));
j.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Request approval for Kiranam Registration - " + KiranamUserId);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(j, "Select your mail account to send mail for Approval"));
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Gmail seems to ignore `Intent` extras. Try this instead:

```
Intent j = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
j.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:appsupport@prali.in" +
    "?subject=Request approval for Kiranam Registration - " + KiranamUserId));
j.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Request approval for Kiranam Registration - " + KiranamUserId);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(j, "Select your mail account to send mail for Approval"));
```

Comment: it works fine for me. How can I add also an html text and a zip file as attachment?

Comment: @capo11 body text is possible using the URL parameter `body`. Note that the content **must be** URL-encoded! Attachments are not possible.

Comment: @capo11also have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15389351/unable-to-send-email-with-attachments-from-my-app-using-intents-gmail there is a solution using `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE` for Gmail with attachments (but may no longer work, you'll have to try it).

Comment: Thankyou!  Adding it to setData works.  I didn't bother adding the EXTRA_SUBJECT.  It seems to work fine without it on gmail and outlook.  Not sure about other email clients.

Answer (score 5):

`ACTION_SENDTO` [is not documented to support any extras](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SENDTO). So, while you are welcome to include `EXTRA_SUBJECT`, do not assume that any particular app responding to `ACTION_SENDTO` will honor it.

Even for places where extras are documented — `ACTION_SEND` documents support for `EXTRA_SUBJECT`, for example — there is no requirement for every app to honor every extra.

Answer (score 4):

I found that setting the data part of the intent to `Uri.parse("mailto:")` and defining the email via `Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL` works fine:

```
Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("mailto:")).apply {
    putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, arrayOf("help@test.com"))
    putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Support request")
    putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hello team!")
}
```