# Missing start boundary Exception when sending messages with an attachment file in Tomcat

Tags: spring, tomcat, jetty, jakarta-mail, apache-camel

I've found a number of possible matches to this problem but none that work for me.

I'm using Apache Camel to deliver a file as an email attachement. It works perfectly using the following maven goals:

jetty:run
jetty:run-exploded
jetty:run-war

I'm using java 1.6. My deployment container is tomcat6. In tomcat6 and tomcat7 I get the following exception:

org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Missing start boundary; message exception details (1) are:
Failed message 1:
javax.mail.MessagingException: Missing start boundary
at javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.parsebm(MimeMultipart.java:882)

The advice on the web suggests this is a class loader problem. Its either that the activation-1.1.jar or mail-1.4.4.jar files are not being found, or the mailcap file in mail-1.4.4.jar is not being found.

I've tried putting these jar files in tomcat/lib. I've tried copying the mailcap from the jar file into the META-INF directory of the exploded war. Neither of these make a difference.

Versions:

Windows: Apache Tomcat/7.0.5 JDK 1.6.0_27-b07 Apache Camel 2.8.0-fuse-00-08

Linux - the versions that come with ubuntu 10.04 LTS - I'll check these later and add.

This is a simplified version of my camel routes:

```
<route id="uploadFileForm">
    <from uri="jetty:http://0.0.0.0:9095/premier"/>
    <to uri="velocity:form.html"/>
</route>
<route id="uploadFile">
    <from uri="jetty:http://0.0.0.0:9095/fup"/>
    <to uri="log:mail?showBody=true&amp;showHeaders=true"/>
    <to uri="smtp://localhost"/>
    <setHeader headerName="content-type"><constant>text/plain</constant></setHeader>
    <setBody><constant>Message Sent</constant></setBody>
</route>
```

This is what the log shows:

```
[4 - seda://mail-ws-audio-files] mail                           INFO  Exchange[ExchangePattern:InOut, Headers:{Connection=Keep-Alive, CamelHttpServletRequest=org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.MultiPartFilter$Wrapper@bb32c5, upfile=D:downloads!37SQFTS.pdf, CamelHttpPath=/fup, subject=BBC Premier League Update - Edition 1, CamelHttpQuery=null, CamelHttpServletResponse=HTTP/1.1 200 

, UntilMessage=until 10:30 GMT when a second bulletin is available (Mon-Fri only), Host=localhost:9095, User-Agent=Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E), Accept-Encoding=gzip, deflate, bulletin_type=am, to=julian.cable@yahoo.com, cc=admin@localhost, breadcrumbId=ID-B1-L0N336601-58958-1335935026761-0-2, CamelHttpUrl=http://localhost:9095/fup, Content-Length=24896, Referer=http://localhost:9095/premier, from=jfbcable@gmail.com, Accept=image/jpeg, application/x-ms-application, image/gif, application/xaml+xml, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, */*, Accept-Language=en-GB, Content-Type=multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------7dc3a8371906f6, CamelHttpUri=/fup, Cache-Control=no-cache, CamelHttpMethod=POST}, BodyType:String, Body:Dear Partner,

    please find attached the latest edition of our file.
```

A minimal example maven project is [here](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0BwhuUU2g0GM9Um1PdGRHV0tfN1k) and the war is [here](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0BwhuUU2g0GM9dmlZOVZMMlg5N2M). If you run the project in eclipse or with

```
mvn jetty:run
```

and then use the form at http://localhost:9095/premier

You will get a "cannot contact server" exception. But if you deploy the war to tomcat you will get the missing start boundary exception. If you edit applicationContext.xml and replace the **** with valid values, it will actually send an email.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1969667/1002025 is highly relevant but where should I look for other jars and in a camel spring-dsl environment how can I set the classloader?

Comment: Let's do some debugging before pulling out the shotgun.  You should only get the exception when reading a message; where and how are you reading the message?  What does the session debugging output show?

Comment: I've added a simplified version of my camel routes to the question. The exception happens on the smtp endpoint. The log report shows the headers.

Comment: Bill - sorry, I don't know how to run tomcat under the debugger, and if I run the camel route in eclipse it works. I've made a minimal version and put it here: https://docs.google.com/open?id=0BwhuUU2g0GM9Um1PdGRHV0tfN1k. If you run it with "mvn jetty:run" you get a "can't contact the email server" error. If you deploy it in tomcat you get the "Missing Boundary" error. If you edit the **** bits in the applicationContext.xml file it should actually send the mail.

Comment: Sorry, I know nothing about Camel and it would take me too long to sort through your application and debug it for you.  If all you're doing is **sending** messages, I have no idea why you're getting that exception, since that only occurs when parsing a message.  Maybe Camel is creating the message text itself and then asking JavaMail to read it and send it?

Comment: Fair enough, firstly - I don't have any code in the conventional sense, although I could make some by converting the Spring-DSL xml into its Java equivalent. Secondly, I don't see how there can be a "bug" in the conventional sense, as it works perfectly except in Tomcat. Of course there could be bugs in the underlying Camel adapters to Jetty and Javamail. I'm pretty sure its a class loading problem, I just need help working out how to find it.

Comment: I've dug a little into the camel-mail code and it looks like it decodes the attachments of the incoming JMS/Camel message and rebuilds the attachement list for the mail to send. That may explain why I'm getting a "receive" type error when sending. It also looks like the jetty jars contain some of the javamail classes which might account for a class loading clash.

Comment: Oh ya, if you've got multiple versions of the JavaMail classes in your classpath, all kinds of bad things can happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried your simplified camel route sample, it works well with mvn jetty:run.

In my Tomcat 7.0.27, Java 6, it actually works. The mail was sent correctly. The only difference is I don't use the:

```
mvn install
```

Instead using:

```
mvn package
```

Then copy the target/test-mail-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war to the Tomcat webapps folder, and start tomcat (bin/startup.sh or bin/startup.bat).

Hope this works for you as well.

My suggestion that you pick the same Tomcat version as I had and follow the same step.

Other source of problem you should:

1. Check is whether you have environment variable CATALINA_HOME or CATALINA_BASE unsuspectingly to you set to point to other Tomcat installation.
2. Also in the environment variable, check the content of your JRE_HOME or JAVA_HOME (when using JDK), and your CLASSPATH variable. You should set your classpath to $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib:$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext:. or %JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib;%JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/ext;. (the last dot is very important)
3. Substitute JAVA_HOME/lib with JRE_HOME if you are running on JRE only.
4. What version of JVM are you running. I am using Oracle JDK 6. Are you using OpenJDK/J9 or something else?

Comment: Thanks for having a go. On Windows, as I said I'm using Tomcat/7.0.5 Sun/Oracle JDK 1.6.0_27-b07. On linux its Apache Tomcat/6.0.24 1.6.0_24-b07 Sun Microsystems Inc. I always use mvn package and then the web manager to upload the war

Comment: Yup, just moving to 7.0.27 seems to fix it. Not ideal for my production environment but we'll see. Thanks.

Comment: I ran it on Windows 7, Oracle JDK 6 update 31. I have just tried again with Tomcat 7.0.5, seems not to work out-of-the-box. 7.0.5 is beta unstable version.
Glad to see it works for you now.

Comment: 7.0.5 is what came with xampp. I use it for testing on my laptop. Thats easy enough to replace with 7.0.27. Production environment is ubuntu 10.04 LTS which has 6.0.24. I'll have to roll the whole platform forward so will wait for a good reason. Tomcat is only in use because Tech-Ops have seen it before and because Camel Web Console doesn't yet work with Karaf.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a working solution to my problem, but not an answer to my question. My original route set works every way I've tried it except in Tomcat and requires no java code (of my own).

I've taken a brute force approach and moved the jetty generated attachement to the body, and then later in the route, move it back to an attachment. It gets me to something I can deploy, but its a hack.

Still looking for a way to deploy my original route set in Tomcat 6.

Comment: Look at my answer above, I managed to get it running without any hacks.